# SwiftUI Circle line width change stops trim animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to animate the trim attribute of a circle. However, if the animation is running and I change the line width, the animation finishes immediately (and unexpectedly).

Does somebody have an idea what I am doing wrong? I'm sure it's a very simple thing.

Thanks for answering!

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var progress: Double = 0.01
    @State var lineWidth: CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            CircleView(progress: progress, lineWidth: lineWidth)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .onAppear{
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 20)){
                        progress = 1
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation{
                    lineWidth = 40
                }
                
            }, label: {Text("Change Line Width")})
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var progress: Double
    var lineWidth: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: CGFloat(progress))
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can directly do what you hope to do.  The stroking of the line uses the `lineWidth`, so I don't believe you can animate it with a separate time interval.

What you can do is change the `lineWidth` over time so that while the circle animation is running and redrawing the circle, it will use the new values.

With that in mind, I created the function `changeValueOverTime(value:newValue:duration)` to do this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var progress: Double = 0.01
    @State var lineWidth: CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            CircleView(progress: progress, lineWidth: $lineWidth)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .onAppear{
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 20)){
                        progress = 1
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                changeValueOverTime(value: $lineWidth, newValue: 40, duration: 0.5)
                
            }, label: {Text("Change Line Width")})
        }
    }
    
    func changeValueOverTime(value: Binding<CGFloat>, newValue: CGFloat, duration: Double) {
        
        let timeIncrements = 0.02
        let steps = Int(duration / timeIncrements)
        var count = 0
        let increment = (newValue -  value.wrappedValue) / CGFloat(steps)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeIncrements, repeats: true) { timer in
            value.wrappedValue += increment
            count += 1
            if count == steps {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why can’t I use the normal withAnimation for both values (lineWidth and progress)?

Comment: Both values affect the stroking of the circle animation and seem inseparable.  When an animation is drawn, the value change has already happened and you are just viewing what happened in the past.  The change in stroke width can be animated at the same time as the stroking, but they're done at the same speed.  My workaround (cheat) is to change the lineWidth over time and the already running animation just uses the latest lineWidth while redrawing the circle.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Weird that there is no way to do this with withAnimation...?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove second animation and all will work. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
Button(action: {
   lineWidth = 40     // << no animation here !!
}, label: {Text("Change Line Width")})
```

Comment: But why doesn’t it work with the second animation enabled? Unfortunately, I‘d like to control the line width animation separately.